# detect image change event

Tags: javascript

How do I detect the change if I have mouseover a thumbnail image, the main image will replace with the thumbnail, I believe `onLoad()` does only fire once.

Comment: Could you please clear your question

Answer (score 2):

*If i understand you correctly :*

Use `onmouseover`.  `onload` is a document event handler.

```
<img src="images/oldImage.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/newImage.jpg'; alert("Mouse detected over thumbnail.  New fullsize Image Loaded!");>
```